# JavaScript Elemento não definido

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo problemas para rodar o seguinte código JavaScript

```
//dynamic table 
function chamadaTable(){
    const detailsbody = document.querySelector("#maintenance > tbody");
    console.log(detailsbody);
    loadDetailsbody();
    populateTable();    
}

function loadDetailsbody(){
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open("GET","http://URL/project/consult", true);
        request.onload = () =>{

            try{
                const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                populateTable(json);
            }

            catch(e){
                console.warn("Não foi possivel carregar a tabela!");
            }
        };

        request.send();
    }

function populateTable(json){
    //clear out existing table data
    while(detailsbody.firstChild){
        detailsbody.removeChild(detailsbody.firstChild);
    }
}
```

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro na função **populateTable**:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: detailsbody is not defined

sendo que estou definindo detailsbody logo no inicio do código.

o que está de errado no meu código ?

Comment: avaliando somente este trecho a variável `detailsbody` é preenchida na função `chamadaTable` que não é chamada em canto nenhum, talvez seja este o seu problema

Comment: Olá @MarceloVismari na verdade estou chamando esse método em outro javaScript, acredito que não seja esse o problema

Comment: retire o `const` da variável `detailsbody` para que ela se torne global e faça um teste. Se funcionar depois declare esta variável em algum lugar que o populateTable possa acessar. Acredito que seja isto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde, tem duas questões ai, 1-o código é Assincrono e a function populateTable() está sendo executado dentro da function chamadaTable() após chamar o loadDetailsbody() quando deve ficar apenas no método request.onload, 2- dentro de populateTable voce tenta acessar detailsbody que não existe nesse contexto, coloque o codigo :

```
const detailsbody = document.querySelector("#maintenance > tbody");
```

fora da function chamadaTable() para ele existir em um contexto global